# PSQL Restore db file with xz

Tags: postgresql, xz

I created backup file psql.bak.xz of db, how to restore this file to db straight (without use unxz)?

I used this command to compress file:

```
pg_dump 2016 | xz > backups/psql.bak.xz
```

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 9):

You can just uncompress and pipe it to psql

```
xzcat backups/psql.bak.xz | psql db
```

Comment: what if i want to clean restore the database